# -32602: Unknown SS58 address format

Tags: ss58format

I ran into this problem while testing a new parachain.

```
balances.transferKeepAlive
-32602: Unknown SS58 address format `129`. ` `To support this address format, you need to call `set_default_ss58_version` at node start up.
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem because 129 was not registered.
https://github.com/paritytech/ss58-registry/blob/main/ss58-registry.json